# PDO Insert Doesn't Throw Error or Insert Form Data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am making the switch from MYSQL to PDO and on my form it will not insert the form data into the DB. What is strange is that it doesn't throw any errors but redirects to the success page without inserting the data. Here is my code:

```
    <?php
session_start();

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'XXXXXXX.hostedresource.com';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'XXXXXX';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'XXXXXXXX';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=XXXXXX;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
      array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    //echo 'Connected to database';
  }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }

$loan_amount = trim($_POST['loan_amount']);
$loan_type = trim($_POST['loan_type']);
$debt_amount = trim($_POST['debt_amount']);
$first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = trim($_POST['last_name']);    
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$zip = trim($_POST['zip']);


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
 try {
   $sql="INSERT INTO leads (loan_amount, loan_type, debt_amount, first_name, last_name, email, phone, zip, reg_date) VALUES (:loan_amount, :loan_type, :debt_amount, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :zip,  NOW())";
   $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $statement->bindValue(':loan_amount', $loan_amount);
   $statement->bindValue(':loan_type', $loan_type);
   $statement->bindValue(':debt_amount', $debt_amount);
   $statement->bindValue(':first_name', $first_name);
   $statement->bindValue(':last_name', $last_name);
   $statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
   $statement->bindValue(':phone', $phone);
   $statement->bindValue(':zip', $zip);
   $statement->execute(); 

  }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
    }

   header('Location: /success.php'); 

}


?>
```

Comment: You might need to pass your DB connection as a parameter for `$loan_amount = trim($_POST['loan_amount']);` and all others. I.e.: `$loan_amount = trim($pdo, $_POST['loan_amount']);` then do it for all the others ones. However, I'm not 100% sure about this, when it comes to PDO, whether it does this automatically.

Comment: Can you verify that your table doesn't only allow unique inserts?

Comment: That threw this error: Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in...

Comment: Also in general you may want to specify a bind type.PDO::PARAM_STR for example

Comment: Fred: WTF? trim just trims whitespace from strings

Comment: Typo in `$password = 'XXXXXXXX;`. Missing the closing `'`.

Comment: @Shawn I don't have any of the fields set in the table as unique

Comment: Ok, well I think there's something breaking your code, if you notice by SO's syntax highlighting. Maybe a missing semi-colon, or a brace. I don't know, hard to tell. Unless it's a typo.

Comment: @j08691 it's actually closed I accidentally removed it when entering XXXX

Comment: @tonjaggart can you check the insert status (this is not the exception)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: @Shawn here is what I get: Fatal error: Non-static method PDOStatement::rowCount() cannot be called statically then I tried the if statement from the docs and it just forwards to the success page

Comment: @Fred hrm... wtf indeed. In no way, at least according to php.net, which I think is the reference for php, does trim() has anything to do with being passed a PDO object as a parameter... `string trim ( string $str [, string $charlist = " \t\n\r\0\x0B" ] )` $pdo has absolutely nothing to do here...

Comment: If this is indeed a typo on your part (the missing quote) in `$password = 'XXXXXXXX;` can you fix it so that it reads as `$password = 'XXXXXXXX';` --- it's throwing off syntax highlighting here. I could have edited it, but I rather let you make that decision. @tonjaggart

Comment: @Shawn made and edit and got this response: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: @tonjaggart that means it "worked", at least as far as sql errors. Although i do see something else that i dont htink is working... array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); ... should be $pdo>setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); That line of code looks like a php error would result?

Comment: @Shawn, array of options also can be passed to PDO constructor, so OP can just change the position of `)`.

Comment: @u_mulder but its not in the constructor. Look at end of line its a semicolon not a comma.

Comment: @Shawn I see it, as i said - OP can just change the position of `)` and remove `;` of course.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Trimming strings has nothing to do with database connection. Quick check of PHP manual would tell you that: http://cz1.php.net/trim

Comment: Thanks for the info. As I stated in my original comment, I wrote "might" & "However, I'm not 100% sure about this, when it comes to PDO, whether it does this automatically", hence my "not knowing" if `TRIM` required a DB connection or not. People can't expect me to know what every function needs or does not need in order for it to work properly. I can't be branded as "ignorant", but more like `not-yet-informed` (till now). It's like some expect that it's embedded in our DNA as soon as we're born to know these things. So, thanks again for the info, it's appreciated and "noted". @OndřejMirtes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with syntax:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=XXXXXX;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

You have a closing parenthesis and semi-colon at the end of your constructor which is breaking your code. You either need:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=XXXXXX;charset=utf8", $username, $password,
array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

OR

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=XXXXXX;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```